# Show content inside div/section, when create a new div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm creating a "widget / popup" which you can accept or decline. I've created a div with 3 buttons (hide, accept and decline). When i show it with display:block, it's displayed properly. But if I make a new one, with the same id, the same widget is displayed, but without the buttons.

this is the HTML

```
<div id="feedback" class="alert alert-success alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:block" >
    <button id="hide" >X</button>
    <button id="decline" >Weigeren</button>
    <button id="accept" >Akkoord</button>
</div>
```

And this is where i make a new pop-up (on button click):

```
let fw = new FeedbackWidget("feedback")
$("#ok").on("click", function(){
    fw.show("NEW WIDGET", "success"); // first param is message and second is the type (green or red)
});
```

The show method is to display the widget / pop-up depending on the parameters.

So, the problem is: how to display a new div with the buttons, without losing the functionalities of these buttons?

Comment: `if I make a new one, with the same id...` this is your problem. `id` attributes within the same DOM need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have an idea to do it in a different way, with the same functionalities?

Comment: Sure, you need to clone the HTML content for the popup giving it a new `id` each time, or better yet, search for a better library which does not rely on ids and can use grouped selectors, such as classes.

Comment: you can make a DOM of buttons in JS and insert it after 'fw.show("NEW WIDGET", "success");'

Answer (score 0):

I believe, when you try to create a new widget with same id it replace the inner content with its own and display it. so you might not get button in the widget.
This might help you to get button
I just created a scenario when you innertext is get vanished and show different content but not buttons so I have injected button in the popup.

Just look out in your code that you have unique id for buttons.

```js
$("#ok").on("click", function(){

 // your code
 $('#feedback').empty();
 //insert button
 addAcceptButton(document.getElementById('feedback'))
    
});
function addAcceptButton(elem) {
 var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Akkoord";         
elem.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feedback" class="alert alert-success alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:block" >
    <button id="hide" >X</button>
    <button id="decline" >Weigeren</button>
    <button id="accept" >Akkoord</button>
</div>
<button id="ok">
 click here
</button>
<div id="test">
This is test
</div>
```